# Help with solving first order PDE with characteristic method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Take the following PDE:

$$u_x-u_y+(x+y)u=0$$

Express it in standard form,

$$u_x-u_y=-(x+y)u$$

From here, form the characteristic system of equations,

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-1$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-(x+y)$$

Where the first two equations are separable, and yield the following solutions:
$$x=t+f_1(s)$$
$$y=-t-f_2(s)$$
Here I tried to get an expression for the parameter $s$ equating both expressions for $t$:
$$x-f_1(s)=-y-f_2(s)$$
$$x+y=f_1(s)-f_2(s)$$
$$x+y=f_3(s)$$
$$s=f_3^{-1}(x+y)$$
With this at hand, I proceeded to solve the last equation as follows:
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-(x+y)$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-(t+f_1(s)-(t+f_2(s)))$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-(f_1(s)-f_2(s))$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-f_3(s)$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=f_4(s)$$
which yields the following solution:
$$u=f_4(s)(t+f_5(s))$$
$$u=f_4(s)t+f_4(s)f_5(s))$$
$$u=f_4(s)t+f_6(s)$$
substitute now one of the relations for $t$:
$$u=f_4(s)(x-f_1(s))+f_6(s)$$
$$u=f_4(s)x-f_4(s)f_1(s)+f_6(s)$$
$$u=f_4(s)x-f_7(s)+f_6(s)$$
$$u=f_4(s)x+f_8(s)$$
now substitute the value for $s$ to get the final solution,
$$u=f_4(f_3^{-1}(x+y))x+f_8(f_3^{-1}(x+y))$$
$$u=M(x+y)x+N(x+y)$$

This is all well and good but the verification fails, I have traced back my steps but I can't find where I am wrong, and to add insult to injury the teacher told us that the solution should have a term $e^{x+y}$ for which I just can't find a way to get it. What am I missing? Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution needs two corrections:

1. Your fifth equation should be
   $$
   \frac{du}{dt}=-(x+y)\,u. \tag{1}
   $$
   Defining $v=\ln u$, it can be rewritten as
   $$
   \frac{dv}{dt}=-(x+y), \tag{2}
   $$
   so almost all of your subsequent equations remain valid if you replace $u$ with $v$.
2. In your next to last equation, you must recall that $f_4$ was previously defined as $-f_3$, so the last equation should be (replacing $u$ with $v$)
   $$
   v=-x(x+y)+N(x+y). \tag{3}
   $$
   Finally, since $v=\ln u$, we may rewrite $(3)$ as
   $$
   u(x,y)=f(x+y)\,e^{-x(x+y)}, \tag{4}
   $$
   where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_x-u_y=-(x+y)u$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1\quad\text{OK.}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-1\quad\text{OK.}$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=-(x+y)\quad\text{isn't correct. It should be}\quad \frac{du}{dt}=-(x+y)u$$
Equivalent writting :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{du}{-(x+y)u}=dt$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-1}$ :
$$x+y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving

$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{x\,dx+(-y)\,dy}{x-(-y)}=\frac{du}{-(x+y)u}\quad\implies\quad \frac12 d(x^2-y^2)=\frac{du}{-u}$
$$u\:e^{\frac12(x^2-y^2)}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implict form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u\:e^{\frac12(x^2-y^2)}=F(x+y)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^{\frac12(y^2-x^2)}F(x+y)}$$

NOTE :

The above result is consistent with the result from Gonçalo :
$$e^{\frac12(y^2-x^2)}F(x+y)=e^{-x(x+y)}f(x+y)\quad\text{with}\quad f(x+y)=e^{\frac12(x+y)^2}F(x+y)$$